# Matplotlib: scatter plot takes a lot of time when plotting large amount of points

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I use scatter plot use large amount of points, the speed is very slow

```
n_samples = 43000
np.random.seed(0)
shifted_gaussian = np.random.randn(n_samples, 2) + np.array([20, 20])

%%time
df=pd.DataFrame(shifted_gaussian, columns=['x','y'])
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='x', y='y', alpha=0.35)
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
```

[image]

After searaching for a while, I found [Speeding up matplotlib scatter plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179928/speeding-up-matplotlib-scatter-plots), but it is three years from now. I want to know,

1. If this is still true to everyone? (I didn't realized the speed problem until recently. Maybe I made some code mistakes.)
2. Is there any way to speed it up? or any workaround, different plot libraries?

Comment: Always look at your plots! Where is the point with the highest density? You don't know because you are just plotting points over points. A heatmap based plot will give you much more information and will be computationally easier to draw.

Comment: Maybe you can reduce the point density by only keeping one of neighbouring points if too many points are grouped up?  It will require more number-crunching beforehand, but should speed up the plotting since way fewer points are plotted.

Comment: @cel, Yes, and that's why I made some other density plots in my research paper. But this scatter plot is mostly to give an intuitive look on the data points (the points are made from some transition, so there is also another scatter plot showing initial points).